# sqlite driven c# application - how to use undolog table to implement undo/redo?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, undo-redo

I have a c# application using a sqlite database as the model.  Undo/redo functionality is partially done; I'm stuck.

So far:
When the application is launched, a table `undolog` (`seq INTEGER, sql TEXT`) is created, and temp triggers are added to the other tables to insert rows into `undolog`.  Each row of `undolog` contains the sql commands required to perform the undo steps.

For example, for the table `Objects` (`objId INTEGER, objName TEXT`), the following triggers are created.

AFTER INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO undolog VALUES( NULL,
                            'DELETE FROM Objects WHERE rowid='||new.rowid);
```

AFTER UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO undolog VALUES( NULL, 
                            'UPDATE Objects SET objID='||quote(old.objID)||',objName='||quote(old.objName)||' WHERE rowid='||old.rowid)
```

BEFORE DELETE:

```
INSERT INTO undolog VALUES(NULL, 'INSERT INTO Objects(rowid,objID,objName) VALUES('||old.rowid||','||quote(old.objID)||','||quote(old.objName)||')');
```

So far all good.  When tables are modified, the right rows are inserted into undolog.  If I were to execute the contents of the sql column in reverse, the table modifications would be undone.

I have been following the wonderful [SQLite undo-redo example](https://www.sqlite.org/undoredo.html) but when it comes to implementing the undo/redo stack, I don't understand at all.  I'm completely lost.

There is a hole in my c# code sitting in between the user clicking undo and redo in any order he/she likes, and `undolog`.  This is what I've got so far: user clicks undo, get the SQL from the latest `undolog` row then delete the row.  Execute the sql.  But then a new row is created in `undolog` in response to the undo action.  This is obviously wrong, but I don't know how to proceed further.

It's a windows forms application using .net framework 4.7.2.  I'm using system.data.sqlite. Building queries in the c# code and executing them.

Comment: Do you need to perform undo-redo at the database level? If that is just an arbitrary choice to add undo-redo functionality I'd suggest it would be easier to use undo/redo stacks. Also the Memento pattern is generally the simplest approach - save copies of state instead of undo methods for all changes.

Comment: I guess the answer is yes.  The DB is the model in the true sense; all inputs from the UI are written to it, then the UI refreshed accordingly.  The undolog table is essentially a way to make the undo-redo SQL code maintainable by auto-generating it.  BTW I've got it working - using undolog and stacks in C# - probably not elegant but it works.  I will post a minimal example below when I get time.